# What is the scene where Reiner and Bertholdt climb the stairs endlessly refer to?

Tags: attack-on-titan

In the Junior High spinoff episode 8, there are scenes where Reiner and Bertholdt climb the school stairs endlessly. Bertholdt keeps trying to suggest to Reiner that something is wrong but Reiner dismisses it each time with the same phrase: "you're imagining things".

There was nothing similar in the anime as far as I could tell. What is this a reference to?

Comment: Up until now, I didn't really pay heed to this spin-off series. But now that I did, there surely is interesting stuff they've put in there...

Answer (score 1):

There's *only one* scene in the anime that matches your description. In **Season 2 Episode 5**

> Reiner and Bertolt stand on a stair, trying to fight off a Titan.
>
>   [image]
>
>
>
>   Also, take a look at this:
>
>   [image]
>   [image]
>
>   It's the **same** cannon with the spider web on it!